# Fill form field in other application from delphi program

Tags: delphi, barcode

I'm working on a simple delphi program that will get the data from a RS232 barcode reader and copy it to wherever the cursor currently is (if it's an editable field). Specifically I will have to make this work with a web broser to fill a form.

The barcode reading part is ok, I get the numeric data back, but I'm stuck on how to find the correct place to paste it. How can i get the current cursor position and send the data there?

Thanks!

Edit: the user will open a form inside a webpage where one of the fields (`<input type="text">`) is for the barcode. When they pull the trigger on the reader I would like to have the field filled

Comment: Here's one way (there may be a much easier one!): Use the IE developer tool (press F12 with the web page loaded) and find the HTML node where the barcode is supposed to go.  Then, load the web page into a TWebBrowser and use its IHtmlDocument2 interface to find the node in code.  You should be able *in code* to set its text to the barcode and click the Submit button or whatever.

Comment: Unfortunately the delphi app is only needed to transfer the barcode data to the web browser, I can't use it for anything else

Comment: Let the program work in background and just send the received barcode as a keyboard input.

Comment: Sorry, what "anything else" do you mean that you can't use it for?

Comment: Yet another question. Do you receive an event that the user pressed the button on a scanner. All what you described is possible, but you need to write a code to focus that form field somewhere. I know only barcode scanners whose behaved like an ordinary keyboard input and for those you've had to have focused the target input field. Do you have some sort of `OnBarcodeScan` event available from your driver ? If not, and your scanner driver only pastes the code into whatever field is focused, you'll need to keep that target field focused.

Comment: I do indeed, but so far I was only able to use the input within the delphi app. What I can't figure out how to do is transfer the code to the focused field in the most foreground application

Comment: @SirRufo: that seems a good idea, I'll look into that

Comment: @TLama if I get it right the OP has an RS232 (serial port) barcode scanner which is reporting the data in some sort of IPC to his/her application. What (s)he want really does nothing with the barcode scanner, the question is about how can he paste text (the source does not matter this time) into the furthermost forms default input field.
**asg2012** Please correct me if I am wrong.